# Error 'xy' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I know this question had been asked many times. But, in my case, I don't know how to solve this issue. Then, I decided to post and need help to solve this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#define MERGE(a,b) a##b
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double x, y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<MERGE(x, y)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> [Error] 'xy' was not declared in this scope

Where is `xy` declared in this code?

If I want to declare it in the main block, what kind of solution should I use?

Comment: the problem is with the `MERGE(x, y)` what do you expect this program to print?

Comment: @jodag thanks for your question. Actually, I just wanna merge x and y :).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by merge. But if `x=5` and `y=3` do you want to print 53? In that case use `cout << x << y << endl;`

Comment: Yay, a literal `xy` problem!

Comment: XY indeed. Marc, we can tell you what went wrong, but to offer a solution we need to know what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

`##` is the [**token pasting operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator-hash-hash?view=vs-2019).

It will create some variable in your source code named `xy` which you haven't declared.
If that's what you want in the main function you can declare xy as,

```
double xy{};
```

But, I assume what you want to do here, is to output both of the variables x & y.

Simply change `cout<<MERGE(x, y)<<endl;` to the following.

```
std::cout<< x << " " << y << std::endl;
```

`opeartor<<` can be chained to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

`x##y` makes `xy` according to
https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator.html

This explains the error message. Obviously it is a wrong variable to use in this context.